# Is it possible to have Single Identity server for commerce and CMS?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, identity-server

when we install Sitecore 9.1, identity server is installed and when we install Sitecore Commerce, another Identity server is installed.

Is it possible to have single identity server for both authentication?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore Commerce have you installed?

Comment: Sitecore commerce 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are upgrading from Sitecore Commerce 9.0 follow [the upgrade guide](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.1/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_Upgrade_Guide_for_9.1.pdf).

The Sitecore Identity server is included as part of the Sitecore Experience Platform (XP) 9.1
deployment. The following instructions assume that you completed Sitecore Identity installation as
part of the Sitecore XP upgrade process.
You must make the following configuration changes to use the new Sitecore Identity server:

1. Open IIS Manager, and stop the current SitecoreIdentityServer site.
2. In each environment `config.json` file, set the `SitecoreIdentityServerUrl` to point to the
   URL of the Sitecore Identity service in your Sitecore XP 9.1 deployment.
   For example, navigate to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<CommerceAuthoring_SC9>\wwwroot
   \` folder, open the `config.json` file, expand the `AppSettings` node, and specify the URL of
   the Sitecore Identity server:
   "SitecoreIdentityServerUrl":"https://sxastorefront-identityserver"
   NOTE
   The above example uses the default Sitecore Identity server URL. In your
   deployment, the Sitecore Identity server could have a different name and URL.
3. Repeat step 2 for each environment, for example CommerceAuthoring, CommerceShops,
   CommerceOps and CommerceMinions.
4. Point the Sitecore XC Business Tools to the new Sitecore Identity server. Navigate to the
   `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreBizFx\assets` folder, open the config.json file and
   update the “IdentityServerUri” parameter with the URI of the Sitecore Identity server, for
   example: `"IdentityServerUri":"https://sxastorefront-identityserver"`.
5. Extract the SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.*.zip package and navigate to the IdentityServer
   folder.
6. Copy the `Sitecore.Commerce.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file into the production
   configurDtion folder of the new Sitecore Identity server in Internet Information Service (IIS)
   Manager, (for example: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SXAStorefront-IdentityServer\config\production`).
7. Launch Internet Information Service (IIS) Manage and perform an IIS restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sitecore 9.1 you have just one Identity Server.

Probably you have 2 Identity Server because you didn't update the commerce scripts.

You need to update Commerce scripts to use Identity Server which was installed when you installed XP.

[image]

Comment: I am actually using Sitecore 9.0.2 and Sitecore commerce 9.0.2. Now I have to migrate to Sitecore CMS 9.1 and Sitecore commerce 9.1. So to upgrade sitecore cms 9.0.2 to 9.1, I have to install identity server(as part of upgrade steps) and there is already one more which was installed as part of Sitecore commerce 9.0.2. So finally I will have two identity server. Pls suggest the right approach